# Programming language heritage of the word 'field'

Tags: terminology

What programming language introduced the word "field" to describe what we might call a member variable in C++? What modern programming languages carry on this usage as the preferred term?

I've seen this word used in both a C and C++ context but it always feels a bit foreign. I don't have a copy of  the C standard, but the C++ standard  uses the phrase "member variable". (It does use the word "field" in the phrase "bit-field".) Whenever I hear this I can't help but wonder where the speaker got that word from.

Comment: Actually, fields aren't called member variables in C++. They're called data members.

Comment: @FredOverflow I see both "data member" and "member variable" used in the standard. What is the difference? It seems like data member is the more general term. I see it used in reference to union members and static variables for example.

Comment: After looking through the standard a bit more, it looks like "member variable" is almost only used when contrasting with a non-member variable.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Field* is used in Eiffel, Java, C#, and VB.NET. In Smalltalk and some of its descendants and languages inspired by it (e.g. Ruby), it is called *instance variable*, in Self and languages inspired by it (Newspeak, Io, Korz), it is called *slot*. Simula and Python call it *attribute* (which means something else in C# and something yet different in Ruby), ECMAScript calls it *property* (which is of course something else in C#), C++ calls it *member variable*.

So, the term "field" does not come from one of the OO pioneer languages (Simula or Smalltalk). Eiffel predates Java and C#, so at least of all the languages that I am personally familiar with, Eiffel is the one which is most likely to be the origin of the term.

However, it does seem to be a rather obvious term, in analogy to fields on a form.

Answer (score 6):

The concept / use of field, a logical part of any data, has been with us since at least punched cards/tape.  These fields were typically fixed length.

All of the first languages probably used the term since they were processing punched cards / tape.  I say 'probably' because I used 'All' and did not program using them all.  In the late 60's when I started programming the term 'field' was used in all of the languages I programmed in.

My guess would be that the first use of 'field' in a programming language would be an early IBM assembler, perhaps SPS.